# Dynamic action URL in Django Template

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a form in Django and would like to add the correct id at the end of the URL.  I am not sure how to add the ID at the end dynamically however.  Here's some example code.

```
{% for dealer_payment_account in dealer.dealerpaymentaccount_set.all %}
<p>Account: {{ dealer_payment_account.last_4_digits }}</p>
  <form id="verifyDealerBankAccountForm" action="/verify-dealer-payment-account/{{ dealer_payment_account.id }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Payment</label>
      <input type="text" name="amount">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Specifically I am wondering how to format this:

```
action="/verify-dealer-payment-account/{{ dealer_payment_account.id }}"
```

so that I can add the dealer_payment_accound.id to the end of each form.

Here is the URL:

```
url(r'^verify-dealer-payment-account/(?P<account_number>[0-9]+)/$', verify_dealer_payment_account),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your form in the template this way:

```html
<form action="{% url 'verify_dealer_payment_account' dealer_payment_account.id %}">
```

where: `verify_dealer_payment_account` is a name of the `URL pattern`.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `urlnamespace`

```
<form id="verifyDealerBankAccountForm" action="{% url 'your-verify-dealer-payment-account' dealer_payment_account.id %}" method="POST">
```

**NOTE :** please add your respective url name in `your-verify-dealer-payment-account`

For e.g.

```
path('verify-dealer-payment-account/<str:payment_account_id>',  views.your_view_name, name='your-verify-dealer-payment-account' )
```

The url name `your-verify-dealer-payment-account` is used in template.

Comment: I added the URL above.

Comment: @Jake Mulhern did it work?

Comment: it did work once I added a name to the URL.